# ^x^y Unix trick for the first occurrence of a string in a command in history (Not the last / previous command)

Tags: string, bash, replace, command

`^search^replace` to replace first occurrence of string 'search' with 'replace' in previous command

`!!:gs/search/replace/` to replace all 'search' with 'replace' in previous command

`!<num>:gs/search/replace/` to replace all 'search' with 'replace' in command `<num>` in history.

How can I replace the first occurrence of the 'search' in a particular command <num> in the command history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost said the answer, because you already introduced all the elements needed:

```
!<num>:s/search/replace/
```

select the command you are interested on (`!<num>`) followed by the transformation (`:s/search/replace/`), but this time, ommiting the *global* designator (`g`).